# Restrict access based on IP address to selected directories

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-jessie, restrictions

```
<Directory /var/www/html/admin/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
Allow from myip
</Directory>
```

`Allow from 192.168.1.0/24` - do I need this line? Is this the best way and correct at all to put it in end of file in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf?

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the IP address which you want to restrict instead of 192.168.1.0/24 to the folder specified `<Directory /var/www/html/admin/>`,  without that line how will you restrict the access to the directory?

Also make sure you restart httpd service by following command

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```